# Recursively unmount Bind mount in both User and Mount namespace

Tags: linux, mount, namespace, bind-mount

I am trying to use recursive bind mount in a new user namespace and mount namespace.

This is what I do. Assume `/foo/bar/` and `/foo` are both mount points.
Firstly I do `mount --rbind /foo/bar/ /baz`, and then when I want to unmount it, I get

```
umount: /baz: device is busy.
```

I am sure that there is no other process is using `/baz`.
Then I tried to unmount `/baz/bar`. This time I got

```
unmount: /baz/bar: not mounted.
```

However, I can see `/baz/bar` in `/proc/mounts`.

What is going wrong or how should I bind mount and then unmount in a new user & mount namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You need `umount -l` which will unmount an entire tree in one system call.